# How to add an action flow button on the navigation bar?

Tags: android, menu

From the article ["Say Goodbye to the Menu Button "](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html)
it seems now the menu button is going to the action bar.

> "If you’ve already developed an app to support Android 2.3 and lower,
>   then you might have noticed that when it runs on a device without a
>   hardware Menu button (such as a Honeycomb tablet or Galaxy Nexus), the
>   system adds the action overflow button beside the system navigation. "

But since I do not want the action bar takes the space, and I only need one menu button there, I hope I had a menu button within the navigation bar at the bottom.

How to do that?

[Update] From one aplication's code, it seems if I set the target level is lower, and use the add menu function, the menu button can be put with the navigation bar at the bottom. But anyway, as Samus Arin said, if there is only button for the menu, it doesn't make sense to build a action bar.

Comment: Thanks google for making this design decision for me, I don't know what I would've done without your ingenious placement of a button on a UI element (action bar) that I don't even have the room for. Better yet, make it completely unavailable for display on a UI element (navigation bar) which is already taking up significant real estate, most of which is unused !? Such a great idea for a platform that runs on devices with limited screen space. So much for the genious bar, i mean action bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can develop for newer releases, and then detect if there is a menu-button on the device. If there is not, show your own in the UI.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewConfiguration.html#hasPermanentMenuKey()

Ex.

```
if(ViewConfiguration.hasPermanentMenuKey(context)){ Has menu-button } else { Does not have menu-button, show in UI }
```

As you said, if you want the overflow-button in the navigation-bar you have to set the target-sdk to 13 or lower.

IMO this option should be given to the developer regardless of targetsdk.

UPDATE: hasPermanentMenuKey() can only be used in SDK>13, so you have to check this manually in your code.